# Grouping time values in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to group time values in MS Access. I have a switch statement, but it says the syntax is invalid. I'm not sure why.

```
Switch(
       [Time]<#7:00 AM#, 
           "Before 7:00 AM", 
       [Time] >= #7:00 AM# And [Time]<= #10:00 AM#,
           "Morning", 
       [Time] >#10:00 AM# And [Time]<=#5:00 PM#,
           "Late morning through Afternoon",
       [Time]> #5:00 PM# And [Time]<=#10:00 PM#,
            "Evening",
       [Time] > #10:00 PM#, 
             "After 10:00 PM' 
) AS Time_of_Day
```

The values are being stored in Short Time through an input mask, like this:

```
00:00
```

I have tried to edit the above switch statement to include long time, but it still doesn't work. Could someone please tell me what's wrong with the above switch statement, and whether or not this is a good way to group time values in Access/SQL.

Thanks

Comment: Just an aside, but in your "switch" code, you don't need to check for the lower values. ie. for the second condition, "Time" can never be less than 7am *(that having been caught by the first condition)*. The third condition can never be less than (or equal to) 10am etc.

Comment: You're not storing your times in "short time" format. All date/time values in Jet/ACE databases are stored as 8-byte floating point numbers, where the integer part represents the day (counted starting with Dec. 30, 1899 as 0) and the decimal part represents the time. The text representation of that value is never stored -- it is entirely a presentation issue (though one has to use them in some calculations because they represent the values better than the decimal representations, which are subject to the usual floating-point errors).

Comment: @ Fenton - Short Time is how it's referred to in Access, I'm not just making this up. I just had an error in my code (see the answer I accepted below), but thanks for correcting me on how the data is actually stored, now I can bore everyone at work tomorrow

Comment: "Short Time" is a display format, not a data storage format. The only way your statement "The values are being stored in Short Time" could be true is if you're actually storing the times as text values, not in date/time fields. I neglected to consider that horrendous possibility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this the exact code?  If you have a mismatched quote it could produce your sytax error:

```
"After 10:00 PM'
```

Should be:

```
"After 10:00 PM"
```

Comment: It happens to us all.  Just a suggestion next time format your code(4 spaces).  Thats the only reason I saw it.